# How to do :Sex but with a vertical split?

Tags: split, filesystem, multiple-files, working-directory

When viewing a file `/tmp/vim_split_demo/test.txt`, the parent directory can be opened in a horizontal split screen using the command `:Sex`, as shown in these screenshots:

[image]

What command gives same functionality, except with the screen split vertically instead of horizontally?  Here is a screenshot of the desired results.

[image]

That screenshot came from `vim /tmp/vim_split_demo`, then doing `vsplit` and opening the file in one side.  I've tried `:VSex`, `:Vsex` and a few others, but can't figure it out.  It doesn't matter which side shows the parent directory.

Comment: Yes, the title is very silly but it has all the terms I'm trying to match.  I felt weird Googling for it on my work computer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you're looking for is `:Vexplore`.

From your question, it sounds like you started off knowing only about `:Sexplore` and understandably thought that that was the basic command for bringing up the `vim` file explorer (which is called `netrw`). However, the basic command is just `:Explore`, and `:SExplore` is actually just a variant of that.

The basic `:Explore` version doesn't open `netrw` in a split window, it just replaces the current window with `netrw`.

There are several variants. Here's the full list from the `vim` help documentation, which you can see [here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pi_netrw.html), or in `vim` by typing

`:help explore`

```
 :[N]Explore[!]  [dir]... Explore directory of current file      *:Explore*
 :[N]Hexplore[!] [dir]... Horizontal Split & Explore             *:Hexplore*
 :[N]Lexplore[!] [dir]... Left Explorer Toggle                   *:Lexplore*
 :[N]Sexplore[!] [dir]... Split&Explore current file's directory *:Sexplore*
 :[N]Vexplore[!] [dir]... Vertical   Split & Explore             *:Vexplore*
 :Texplore       [dir]... Tab & Explore                          *:Texplore*
 :Rexplore            ... Return to/from Explorer                *:Rexplore*

 Used with :Explore **/pattern : (also see |netrw-starstar|)
 :Nexplore............. go to next matching file                *:Nexplore*
 :Pexplore............. go to previous matching file            *:Pexplore*
```

For more detailed information about each variant, see the help docs.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning the original Explore and where to get help

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Good suggestion. I updated my answer.